# Elasticsearch adding multi tenant without separate ES instance

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have startup application with my first client in production. Per federal regulations each client data has to be separate i.e. cannot be within a single db/table with a tenant id field to filter.

When I built the application on node.js with elasticsearch.js client, I used the "localhost:9200" as the connection string and a schema that does not have any client identifier. It worked good for the first client. The idea at that time was to either spin a new db server per client or a new instance of ES (elasticsearch) on the same machine.

Both options are no-go because of cost/performance. Is there a way to create a separate ES data directory for each client and route the ES queries based on connection url or by some other means?

Please advice.

Comment: can you create a new `index` for each client?

Comment: @JBone Yes, I can create new index for each client, but is it possible to simply adjust the connection string URL or similar param to route the queries to different index/index dir paths. (without changing the entire codeset to prefix the index name with client ID?